# Using gdal.Warp() in Python to clip a raster to a shapefile is producing errors

Tags: python, raster, gdal, clip, ogr

I have some super simple code that I'm using to clip raster data to US Highways. However, the clip isn't producing pixels for everywhere that the shapefile intersects the raster and I cannot figure out why this is the case. Here is the code:

```
gdal.Warp(input_raster_filepath, output_raster_filepath, cutlineDSName=road_buffered_filepath, cropToCutline=True)
```

Here is the raster and shapefile before the clip:
[image: Raster and Shapefile before the clip]

And here is the raster after the clip:
[image: Raster after the clip]

I was expecting for there to exist a pixel from the raster at every point along the highway but this is not the case. Can anyone explain why? Or could anyonen provide a better method for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to enable the [CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED](https://gdal.org/api/gdalwarp_cpp.html#_CPPv4N15GDALWarpOptions16papszWarpOptionsE) warp option:

> CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED: This defaults to FALSE, but may be set to TRUE to enable ALL_TOUCHEd mode when rasterizing cutline polygons. This is useful to ensure that that all pixels overlapping the cutline polygon will be selected, not just those whose center point falls within the polygon.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

Comment: Please accept the answer as well if it solved the problem.

Comment: I am trying to use this option in Python, but gdal.WarpOptions(CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED=True) returns TypeError: WarpOptions() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cutline_all_touched'. How did you manage to feed that option to warp in Python?

Comment: @TheBackwardsman, [check out the tests for an example](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdalwarp_lib.py#L513-L520)